# Append to Dictionary, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list,

```
print(List)
['x1, y1, z1', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
```

and a dictionary containing three empty lists,

```
print(Dictionary)
{0: [], 1: [], 2: []}
```

I have created with the for loop,

```
for item in List:
    r = item.split(', ')
```

so that,

```
for item in List:
    r = item.split(', ')

    print(r)
    ['x1', 'y1', 'z1']
    ['1', '2', '3']
    ['2', '4', '6']
    ['4', '8', '12']

    print(r[0])
    x1
    1
    2
    4

    ...etc.
```

Now I want to append each item of r[i] to Dictionary[i] so that

```
print(Dictionary)
{0: ['x1', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y1', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z1', '3', '6', '12']}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your list has four items in it. Do you really only want the first three in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this = ['x1, y1, z1', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
that = {0: [], 1: [], 2: []}

for i in that.keys():
    for item in this:
        r = item.split(', ')

        that[i].append(r[i])
```

In general, I wouldn't call my lists "List" or my dictionaries "Dictionary" :P. You'll get away with it here but I feel like at some point you're likely to run into a reserved word problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this cleaner with list and dict comprehension:

```
my_list = ['x1, y1, z1', '1, 2, 3', '2, 4, 6', '4, 8, 12']
cleaned_list = [x.split(', ') for x in my_list]

my_dict = {index: list(lst) for index, lst in enumerate(zip(*cleaned_list))}

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{0: ['x1', '1', '2', '4'], 1: ['y1', '2', '4', '8'], 2: ['z1', '3', '6', '12']}
```

**- Edit (from jpp's comment) -**

You could write the `dict` comprehension shorter (and possibly more readable) if you just leave it to the constructor but then the values will be tuples instead of lists. Up to you:

```
my_dict = dict(enumerate(zip(*cleaned_list)))
```

Output:

```
{0: ('x1', '1', '2', '4'), 1: ('y1', '2', '4', '8'), 2: ('z1', '3', '6', '12')}
```

Comment: Or even, if tuples are not a problem, `dict(enumerate(zip(*cleaned_list)))`.

Comment: I did it this way just so it would be a `list` instead of `tuple`, but that way is definitely shorter. I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the desired list from the dictionary and append the item

```
for item in List:
    r = item.split(',')
    Dictionary[0].append(r[0])
    Dictionary[1].append(r[1])
    Dictionary[2].append(r[2])
```

Or more succinctly

```
for item in List:
    for i, x in enumerate(item.split(',')):
        Dictionary[i].append(x)
```